# How to screen shot a UAC prompt?

Tags: windows, uac, screenshot

I'm trying to document a work flow with a series of screen shots.  At one point in the flow, a UAC prompt appears, and I'd like to grab a bitmap of it to make my storyboard complete.  Because UAC prompts are on a virtual desktop (or something like that), the usual Alt+PrintScreen doesn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're alright with not using glassless prompts against a dim background, you can adjust the UAC setting one notch down to disable the dimming and should be able to Alt+Prnt Scrn the prompt.

Comment: Connect via Team viewer, then take screenshot from menu.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This method using the group policy editor should do the job:

> 1) Run gpedit.msc
>  2) Under Computer
>   Configuration\Windows
>   Settings\Security Settings\Local
>   Policies\SecurityOptions:
>
> Change “User Account Control: Switch
>   to the secure desktop when prompting
>   for elevation” to disabled

Undo this change after the screenshot, because it makes the system less secure!

Comment: although GPEdit is way more trouble than the UAC settings dialog, I give you credit for reminding @Adrian to put it back to normal afterwards.

Comment: On my windows, the "Switch to the secure desktop..." displays as `@appinfo.dll,-206`. Took me a while to find it.

Answer (score 22):

Change your UAC settings to disable the secure desktop, and then you can take the screenshot. In Windows 7, this is one of the options on the UAC slider, in Vista, I believe you need to configure the Security Policy.

Alternatively, run Windows in a VM and take a screenshot of that.

Answer (score 9):

**A step by step Guide**

`Step 1`. Right click on the Program that you want to install and choose 'Run as administrator'.

[image]

`Step 2`. Now when the UAC Prompt appears, click on 'Change when these notifications appear'.

[image]

`Step 3`. Take the security Bar one-step down. Be sure to find that 'do not dim my desktop' is in the description. Now click on 'OK'.

[image]

Click on 'yes' when the UAC ask for permission.

`Step 4`. Now close all UAC Prompt dialog box. Again start from the beginning. You are now able to take a screenshot of the UAC Prompt dialog box with keyboard's **print screen** button or ms **snipping tool**.

**Note that** it will make your system less secure. So, make the security level as previous after the completion of your need.

Comment: Alternatively, for Windows 10, at least: Use Start + U to open settings > search "UAC" > open "Change User Account Control settings" > continue from step 3

Answer (score 8):

You can also remote desktop to the Windows 7 machine and run the screenshotter (or video capture) on the other machine. I've used this very successfully.

Comment: nice! I was pondering in front of a remote desktop UAC for a solution

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative to [Michael Goldshteyns answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4046954/2154717)

You can more quickly achieve the same by copying the first registry command below and pasting it into an [elevated command prompt](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/e/elevated.htm), then hit enter.

### To turn **off** PromptOnSecureDesktop:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /V "PromptOnSecureDesktop" /T "REG_DWORD" /D "0x00000000" /F 1>NUL
```

This will turn off [SecureDesktop](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/how-does-the-windows-secure-desktop-mode-work), leaving the computer vulnerable, but you will be able to screenshot the UAC prompts.

[image: Screenshot of a UAC prompt without SecureDesktop]

> *All elevation requests go to the interactive user's desktop. Prompt behavior policy settings for administrators and standard users are used.*

### To turn **on** PromptOnSecureDesktop:

This will turn on [SecureDesktop](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/how-does-the-windows-secure-desktop-mode-work).

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /V "PromptOnSecureDesktop" /T "REG_DWORD" /D "0x00000001" /F 1>NUL
```

[image: Screenshot of a UAC prompt with SecureDesktop activated]

> *All elevation requests go to the secure desktop regardless of prompt behavior policy settings for administrators and standard users.*

**⚠ Important: After you are done, make sure you revert the command by turning PromptOnSecureDesktop off.**

Answer (score -6):

Simple method: Use windows accessory SnippingTool from MS. It just works!

Comment: how did you do it? Did you launch Snipping tool after UAC is shown? It works for me this way

Comment: ok I think this was NOT universal solution. It worked for me for one dialog that tried hard to pretend to be like UAC (like disabling screenshot etc). Sorry for the confusion!