# How can I get the screen of the UAC-window?

Tags: windows, screenshot, uac

Windows 8.1 When I try to launch `gpedit.msc` according [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046940/how-to-screen-shot-a-uac-prompt) info, Windows can't find such file.

How can I get the screen of the UAC-window with a question of confirmation on start of the program? I need it in a sample of my documentation. I press the Print Screen button, but the clipboard has nothing.

Comment: I added info about the Windows version and about the `gpedit.msc`.

Comment: Is this some kind of home edition of Windows ? Have you checked if gpedit.msc can be found somewhere on the disk but not in the search path ?

Comment: When I press the `Win` + `Break` I see OS name as "Windows 8.1" without info about its sort (home, professional, enterprise, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found decission [here](http://www.download3k.com/articles/How-to-screen-capture-a-User-Account-Control-UAC-prompt-in-Windows-10-or-8-00450). I tried "Method 2" and it works fine.