# Sikulix/Jython UAC automation

Tags: jython, sikuli

I was wondering if anyone had any luck automating through UAC pop-ups during installer automation?

I have an existing Automated installer code but it fails at the UAC area due to Sikuli not using keyboard/mouse during this step...

Anyone had any luck here? or no a way to do this in Jython?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The reason Sikuli doesn't work in this scenarios is because the UAC dialog is displayed in a "Secure desktop" which you can read more about [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3762/7179). Secure desktop prevents all interaction so even you attempt to take a screenshot of the UAC dialog itself, it will fail.

That being said, there is a workaround. You can disable switching to secure desktop by following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4046954/1119381):

1. Run `gpedit.msc`
2. Under `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\SecurityOptions`,
   change "*User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation*" to disabled.