# Numeric file name for MSI created with WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

When I run my WiX installer it triggers User Access Control which asks for confirmation to run the MSI, the MSI file name is displayed as "7-digit number.msi" (e.g. "3858264.msi").

Is there a way to change that name to something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***Digit File Name***: I have seen signed packages display the behavior you report: seeing a digit-file name. Please try this:
>   [Odd 'Program name' when installing signed msi installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863137/odd-program-name-when-installing-signed-msi-installer/6869564#6869564)
>
> [image: UAC]
>
> ***Essentially***: **`signtool.exe /d "Your Software Name"`**
>
> Please try that command and report the results? (we need this resolved - industry problem). [One more sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29015441/129130).

---

I think you actually do sign your MSI, but here is what I originally wrote:

***Digital Signature***: It is a known issue that you need to sign your MSI with an authenticode certificate to have the Manufacturer name show up instead of file names: [Installshield Custom Dialogue Installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51204163/installshield-custom-dialogue-installer)

***UAC Prompt***: "*If you Authenticode-sign your .msi package, Windows will show that as the name. Otherwise, you get MSI's temporary copy of it, which has a random name.*"

Comment: Thank you Stein, that did the job! It looks much better now.

Comment: Cool, please set answer accepted and maybe post a screen shot? Or maybe that is not possible because the UAC is its own context and print screen does not work?

Comment: As you say, I cannot take a screenshot, but I confirm that the /d parameter did the job. Thanks again.

Comment: @Francesco [I discovered a way to get a UAC screenshot here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4046954/129130). Do remember to set that setting back to default if you try it.

Comment: Thanks Stein, I'll remember that if I need it in the future.