# Windows printscreen not working on Software Installation

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I am trying to take screenshots of the license information of the application before installing it onto my test window os.

When I click on the installer, the publisher window pops up asking me whether I want to launch the installer or not; But when I want to take screenshots or printscreen using keyboard shortcuts it doesn't work.

It seems that the keyboard shortcuts is disabled during this pop up install dialog.

All I want is to take screenshots at the publisher certificate information before installing the application.

Can anyone with experience on windows help?

Comment: can you try `shift + window key + s` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UAC***: If you are referring to the UAC prompt that shows up first to ask for elevation, then it happens on a secure desktop separate from your main one and hence the screen shot appears impossible. This separate desktop is a security measure. In actual fact it is perhaps **the core security measure** added to Windows in recent years (don't turn it off permanently).

***Disable UAC Temporarily***: You can disable this security measure temporarily so you can take a screenshot as described here: [**How to get a UAC screenshot**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4046954/129130). Here is a sample screen shot of a UAC prompt for an MSI installation: [Numeric file name for msi created with Wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58153598/numeric-file-name-for-msi-created-with-wix/58154444#58154444)

> Here is the essential procedure inlined:
>
> 1. Run ***`gpedit.msc`***
> 2. Locate: ***`Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\SecurityOptions`***:
> 3. Change ***`"User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation"`*** to disabled
> 4. ***Undo this change after the screenshot or your system will be very insecure!***

Comment: :) That helped a lot.

Comment: Great, case closed!